# Multiple Instances of Jenkins on same port

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to setup multiple Jenkins instances on the same Windows server with the same port number. I dint had much luck to do this.

How can I achieve this?

I can configure Jenkins on a different port on the same server, however, I am unable to run that instance as a service. Is there a document that helps for setting up Multiple instances of Jenkins on the same windows server.

Or I dont mind hosting Jenkins on a different directory if it is going to run on a different port number.

Comment: You can only run Jenkins as a service if you use the default port? That doesn't seem right. Any specific errors?

Comment: Getting a error _WMI.WmiException: StatusServiceExists_

Comment: Sounds like Windows doesn't allow the same Service run twice, regardless on how it is configured.

Comment: I suggest you go over to serverfault.com or maybe superuser.com. They might be able to help you better, as this is definetely off-topic on this site now.

Comment: Can Jenkins be hosted as multiple instances on the same box ? Is this possible?

Comment: It should, maybe not as a service. Try deploying multiple instances with different names manually to a tomcat.

Comment: Only a single process can bind to a port. The normal way to do this is to setup Apache on port 80 (default) and then configure it to "proxy" the other Jenkins instances. That way you end up with each Jenkins instances appearing as a subdirectory in Apache: eg http://localhost/jenkins1, http://localhost/jenkins2, etc

Comment: Have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/91071/two-hudson-master-on-the-same-windows-server